# Know if uptime timer is reset or Android has been rebooted

Tags: java, android, clock, reboot, uptime

I have a independent clock created in my application. The clock runs as a different thread in the activity, starting from a base time set by me. I update the clock using the difference between the uptimemillis when I set the clock, and the current uptimemillis. But the uptimetimer, can be reset by Android, and is ever reset when Android reboot.

I only want to know if the uptime timer is reset, to know if the clock is still reliable.

How?

Comment: `uptimeMillis()` is a `long`. It can handle 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 milliseconds before it would wrap around. That is a fairly long time, so unless you have evidence that it wraps around *significantly* before then, I would not worry about the problem. If you *do* have such evidence, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Maybe you should just use the real time clock to get the absolute time instead of using the system uptime?  As in: `new Date()`

Comment: @CommonsWare I read Android can reset it for internal reason... However uptime timer is reset at reboot. Therefore how i can "fix" this?

Comment: @BaileyS If i use real time clock, if user change it, I cannot know it...

Comment: "However uptime timer is reset at reboot" -- correct. "Therefore how i can "fix" this?" -- stop using `uptimeMillis()`, since you are assuming that it means anything other than the number of milliseconds since the last reboot. "If i use real time clock, if user change it, I cannot know it" -- listen for `ACTION_TIME_CHANGED` broadcasts.

Comment: @Eghes, are you even sure that the uptime clock is immune to user real time clock changes?  Is a user RTC time change really a major issue?

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, if this broadcast work, I found the solution.

Comment: @BaileyS Yes, the issue is I want at least know, when the clock is no more correct. Don't matter why, I want know when I must invalidate it.

Comment: The broadcast looks like a great solution for that... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_CHANGED .  Alternatively you might consider comparing the RTC to the Uptime clock... then you could at least know if only one of them changed, but not both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation you can use [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29)

> elapsedRealtime():
>   Returns milliseconds since boot, including time spent in sleep.

This value will only be reset when the device is restarted. Listen to the broadcast [boot_complete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) and you will know when that is.

The problem with the updateMillis() is clearly noted in the documentation:

> uptimeMillis():
>   Returns milliseconds since boot, not counting time spent in deep sleep. Note: This value may get reset occasionally (before it would otherwise wrap around).

From how I understand the documentation, by using elapsedRealtime your users cannot manipulate your counter.